# Do the rules of basic logic have to presupposed to gain philosophical knowledge?

Tags: logic, epistemology, metaphysics

First, let me apologize if my question is nonsensical in any sense. I do not have any philosophical training whatsoever, but I am really interested in some philosophical questions.

I was thinking about journeying into topics that really interest me, and I thought: what is the most fundamental philosophical question I can ask? Or Where can I start without making any unnecessary presuppositions. My first answers were related to truth for if there is no such thing as "truth" the journey is somewhat meaningless in my view. I went around in some circles regarding the topic, and a thought popped into my head: how can I approach a book if I do not presuppose any rules by which I can evaluate what I am reading; hence, my question.

Now that I am asking the question, it seems like if I presuppose the "rules of logic" or something like "the rules of valid reasoning are correct," I would be encountering something akin to "logical truths" as a corollary. Is it so? Are there other ways to read a philosophical book and evaluate it without presupposing the basic rules of logic?

Comment: Descartes attempted, like you, to avoid "unnecessary presuppositions" and ended up with presupposing what he was trying to establish, the Cartesian circle. Here is some advice from Peirce:"*We must begin with all the prejudices which we actually have when we enter upon the study of philosophy. These prejudices are not to be dispelled by a maxim, for they are things which it does not occur to us can be questioned... A person may, it is true, in the course of his studies, find reason to doubt what he began by believing; but in that case he doubts because he has a positive reason for it*".

Comment: That's a bit like asking: if I want to make a journey to get to some place, where should I start from? And the answer is: you have to start from where you are. There is no point trying to look for presuppositions as a prerequisite for starting the journey. Until you start learning from the great thinkers, you won't know what you should presuppose. And in any case, you'll find that the great thinkers disagree about many, many things, including what you might have thought would be an obvious presupposition. Including, even logic itself. So, just dive in and start learning.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Bumble I guess I am having trouble with the following: let's say I want to ask "does truth exist?" I don't see a way to answer this question without presupposing that some logical truths exist. I think this goes to the Cartesian circle Conifold pointed out but maybe not.

Comment: I would still say, just dive in and read what philosophers have to say about truth. Maybe some of them are right; maybe all of them are wrong; but you won't know until you read them and subject them to critical examination. You might find yourself concluding that nothing is true, but there is no need to presuppose anything. A lot of philosophy is an exercise in "grant this for the sake of argument and see where it leads".